# I use android studio 1.5.1. i took a button and give margins and padding as much i want but it not shown correct postition on different scree size

Tags: android

[Below code generate view like shown in image but it looks good in tablet Screen 7" and not well shown in mobile device any screen size. Its format change in mobile devices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgDAu.jpg)This is my code.its best looking in tablet screen but not properly work in mobile device. Here i use Padding and Margins that i want but it not looks same in Mobile device like tablet. How can i do in android studio. My Apps API level is 11.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/intro_Linear_Layout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_view_Logo"
            android:background="@drawable/goose_logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtview_Welcome"
            android:text="@string/txt_welcome"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#04C244"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_SignIn"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_drawable"
            android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_signUp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_drawable_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="125dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please share screen-shot for expected layout and what your are getting from above code to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/goose_logo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview_Welcome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/txt_welcome"
            android:textColor="#04C244"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_SignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_drawable"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_drawable_2"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```